# Having trouble with sending an email through SMTP Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

So I'm trying to send an email through SMTPlib with Python, but I can't get it to work. I read up on the Microsoft SMTP specs, and put them in accordingly, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
    # Send an email
    SERVER  = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
    PORT    = 587
    USER    = "******@outlook.com"
    PASS    = "myPassWouldBeHere"
    FROM    = USER
    TO      = ["******@gmail.com"]
    SUBJECT = "Test"
    MESSAGE = "Test"
    message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s
%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, MESSAGE)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP()
        server.connect(SERVER, PORT)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(USER,PASS)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print "\nCouldn't connect."
```

I got the code from a keylogger, but I cleaned it up a bit. I read up [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm) on how basic SMTP works, but there are few things like `starttls` (Methods) I don't quite understand.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: What does "*I can't get it to work*" mean? Do you get an error message? Does it crash you PC?

Comment: The immediate problem here is that you are not creating a valid SMTP message. At a minimum, you need an empty line between the headers and the message body; but the proper solution is to use Python's `email` library to create an actually valid SMTP message; pasting together strings only works when your message is trivial, and/or you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this. This works in Python 2.7.

```
def send_mail(recipient, subject, message):

    import smtplib
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

    username = "sender@outlook.com"
    password = "sender's password"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = username
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

    try:
        print('sending mail to ' + recipient + ' on ' + subject)

        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.starttls()
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.login(username, password)
        mailServer.sendmail(username, recipient, msg.as_string())
        mailServer.close()

    except error as e:
        print(str(e))


send_mail('recipient@example.com', 'Sent using Python', 'May the force be with you.')
```

Comment: If the message only has one part, wrapping it in a multipart is obviously redundant.

Comment: It is now 2021, and you should probably not use code which targets the Python `email` library as it was before version 3.6 (2016).

Comment: If you have smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server. errors, in the ehlo commands specify any lowercase string as the parameter.  For more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541840/ssl-error-while-sending-email-using-smtp-with-python