# How to send email with smtplib in Python with outlook account

Tags: python, outlook, smtplib

I was following this post to send an email using my outlook account:
[Having trouble with sending an email through SMTP Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314618/having-trouble-with-sending-an-email-through-smtp-python)

I used that and made a simple test code as follows

```
username='****'
password='***'
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(username, password)
```

But it fails with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-67589181ed6a>", line 7, in <module>
mailServer.login(username, password)

  File "/home/saber/miniconda3/envs/explore/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
raise last_exception

  File "/home/saber/miniconda3/envs/explore/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)

  File "/home/saber/miniconda3/envs/explore/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)

SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [YQXPR0101CA0037.CANPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Not reproducible, it works. Correct username & password?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was missing @outlook.com with my username.

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the account to test it? Please refer to the following code:

```
"""The first step is to create an SMTP object, each object is used for connection 
with one server."""

import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

#Next, log in to the server
server.login("youremailusername", "password")

#Send the mail
msg = "
Hello!" # The /n separates the message from the headers
server.sendmail("you@gmail.com", "target@example.com", msg)
```

Related link: [Using Python to Send Email](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email)

Comment: Thanks. I was missing @outlook.com with my username.