# How to connect to the correct smtp server for sending email using smtp in python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am working for a client and i have to send mail with attachments from my work email id (myname@mycompanydomain.com) in outlook using SMTP.

I used smtp.outlook.com as a server it was not working, so how to find correct server of the domain?

**SERVER=?**

```
with smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 587) as server:

    server.starttls()
    print("connected to server")
    server.login(user, PASS)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, text)
```

Comment: You need to have an account or permission to send via SMTP - the days of open relays are long gone.  Do you have an account with outlook.com?  Have you seen posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312557/how-to-send-email-with-smtplib-in-python-with-outlook-account#53318339)?  What does "not working" mean in this case?

Comment: Hi stdunbar, I have an account in Outlook eg: myname@companyname.com . The task is to send mail to my company networks eg: teammatename@companyname.com. But I'm not sure what server i have to use. When I tried with smtp-mail.outlook.com. The code was running for long time. So I don't know if I'm using correct SMTP server to connect

Comment: According to some simple searches, you should be using `smtp-mail.outlook.com`.